# How to use localStorage with useReducer hook?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, local-storage, use-reducer

I have a todo-app,created with useReducer and I need to save them to localStorage, but I got an error.What might be wrong here?

```js
const [{ todos, todoCount }, dispatch] = useReducer(
    reducer,
    {
      todos: [],
      todoCount: 0
    },
    (initial) => JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todos")) || initial
  );
 
  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(todos));
  }, [todos]);
```

I get this error:
A cross-origin error was thrown. React doesn't have access to the actual error object in development. See https://reactjs.org/link/crossorigin-error for more information.

When I wrote a simple counter app with useReducer, I saved to localStorage same way as this, but with todo it doesn't work

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Please also post the error message. What makes you think so little of its content that you simply ignore it?

Answer (score 0):

Need to use useContext+useReducer+localStorage:

```js
 const initialState = {
    todos:
      localStorage.getItem("todos") == null
        ? []
        : JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todos"))
  };
  const [{ todos }, dispatch] = useReducer(
    reducer,
    /* {
      todos: [],
      todoCount: 0
    }*/
    initialState
  );
  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(todos));
  }, [todos]);
```

Comment: I am facing this same situation. can you please help me with my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76910832/how-to-get-text-from-localstorage-having-usereducer-in-reactjs)